# Installing OpenCV on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, opencv

Is it possible to install OpenCV on a MacOS El Capitan and code in Swift for a Mac **not for the iPhone** ? All I see on the Internet are procedures for iOS (UIKit, etc.). If it is possible can you point me to the right procedure, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can tell you how to download, configure, build and install OpenCV from source on El Capitan, and tell you what you'll get in terms of files and libraries, but I don't know the Swift side of things. I am happy to look inside my build for you and tell you if any files you would need are there.

Comment: I succeeded to install openCV and a wrapper to continue coding with Swift. There are good tutorials on YouTube for this. However, it seems to work only for iOS not MacOS...

Comment: Edit -- I inserted these two #undef lines in the OpenCVClass.mm file

#import "openCVClass.h"
#undef NO
#undef check
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Now XCode issues many "Apple Mach-O linker warnings" saying that the built is intended for iOS not for MacOS, and that this will be considered as an error in the future. Furthermore, in older YouTube tutorials they say to download openCV sources "for Linux/MacOS" while there are only sources "for iOS" available in the latest versions... Still puzzled!